# What does this iptables command do?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

Does `iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT` open all ports?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see? Type `sudo iptables -L` after executing it. Also, try to generate some network traffic to see if it's allowed/denied.

Comment: @faif: Experimenting can be tricky: if you try a little traffic and see everything accepted, you can't be sure there aren't some obscure packets that will be rejected. Better advice is to read the documentation, this is an extremely simple case.

Comment: It can be really tricky if you're remoted in via ssh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will accept all traffic that is inbound and destined for this computer; all ports, all protocols, all users, all states. Remember that port isn't the only thing you have to think about when writing a firewall on a Linux System. Any traffic that is outbound or destined for another computer may have different rules. However if your rules are this, for example

```
iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -j DROP
```

the second rule will end up being before the first and all traffic will be dropped. If you want to allow all traffic. I generally recommend using  `-A` instead of `-I` when writing a firewall script so the order is obvious. Also if you just want to allow everything, you'd be better off setting the policy for the chain.

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

will tell everything that hasn't matched another rule at the end of INPUT to be allowed.

Answer (score 3):

`iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT`

The above command will **INSERT** (**-I**) a new rule at **chain position 1** (understood by omission) that matches every packet crossing the **INPUT** chain (because their are no filters) and will **ACCEPT** it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This command creates a rule that will be checked first (`-I`) for incoming packets (`INPUT`); the rule matches every packet (no filter) and allows them (`-j ACCEPT`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, provided that the packet is not dropped in `-t raw`.